# Error: Invalid timestamp: '2017/05/16 19:33:49' BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a string `'2017/05/16 19:33:49'` and I'm getting an error when I try to convert it to the `TIMESTAMP`:

> Error: Invalid timestamp: '2017/05/16 19:33:49'

I want to use `CAST` function to convert it to `TIMESTAMP`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", "2017/05/16 19:33:49") as parsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST("2017/05/16 19:33:49" AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: Same error: **Error: Invalid timestamp: '2017/05/16 19:33:49'**

Comment: try this once SELECT TIMESTAMP("2017/05/16 19:33:49");